# Is there any potential problem when returning a std::future from a local std::promise?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

Here is the example [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/fvx6T35WM):

```
#include<future>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    auto f=[](){
        std::promise<int> promise_;   //Since `promise_` is a local variable, is there any potential problem?
        auto future_ = promise_.get_future();
        promise_.set_value(1);

        return future_;
    }();

    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I asked the same question here: [Is it okay for std::future to outlive a std::promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811371/is-it-okay-for-stdfuture-to-outlive-a-stdpromise)

Comment: @jtbandes Sorry, I can't the said post could answer my question.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Once the `promise_` is destroyed, it just releases the shared state. The shared state still exists, since it has been associated with `future_` (and this association is then moved to `f`).

Comment: @Daniel Langr You say that once the promise_ is destroyed, it just releases the shared state. So I think you mean the shared state does not exist anymore. But in the next sentence, you say the shared state still exists, since it has been associated with future_. I am really confused.

Comment: @John Releasing the shared state by a promise doesn't imply that the shared state "does not exist anymore". Look to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise): _"If this was the last such reference, the shared state is destroyed."_ This does not apply here, since the future object _references_ the shared state as well.